# Error while reading pdf using MODE_WORLD_READABLE?

Tags: android, file, pdf, path

I have made an app which downloads the pdf from the server and stores it in

```
/data/data/<package_name>files
```

using this code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(pdfFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
fos.close();
```

But when reading these file from the pdf reader app which I already have on the device is sometimes showing black screen and sometimes displays the file with annoying fonts. The code I am using is:

```
File file = new File("/data/data/<package_Name>/files/pdffile");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try
{
    startActivity(pdfIntent);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Activity Not Found Exception",e.toString());
}
```

I have tried the same code with the same files at other path(in sdcard) they work fine.
Please help me and tell me what should have gone wrong.

What should be a possible way to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use method 
[android.content.Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29).

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

This code works for me:

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), pdfFileName);
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
try {
     startActivity(pdfIntent);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Log.e("Activity Not Found Exception",e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 methods to achieve what you want:

---

## 1) Using SDCARD

You save downloaded `pdf` somewhere **SDCARD**. Something like this:

Instead of creating a file:

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pdffile");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
fos.close();
...
```

And you use `pdfFile` when creating an Intent.

---

## 2) Using custom `ContentProvider`

The second method can be used if you still do not want to use your SDCARD storage. You can use your app's `CacheDir` (you will download your file there). This involves creating your own `ContentProvider`, and after that you will be able to pass corresponding URI to the pdfreader app.

Details on how to do this all are [here](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974).

---

There is no known other methods to open any downloaded file in 3rd party app in Android.

Comment: Your claim is untrue.  It is true that the method the poster wants to use is *not currently encouraged*, and some apps may refuse to even attempt to access such paths *as a matter of principle* - but that doesn't mean that Android will prevent them from doing so *if they try*.